# IllegalArgumentException: width should be > 0?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, width, illegalargumentexception

I use `Asynctask` to set the image to `RecyclerView` when the page is executed

`Asynctask` takes a recyclerView's width and height

However, this error occurs `'IllegalArgumentException: width should be > 0'`

I looked up similar cases and saw that it was a problem to run too soon

So I tried `onPause`, `onStart`, and `onPostCreated`, but the same result came up

Put it in the button and run it to get the result I want

Therefore, I think that the point of execution is the problem

When should I call this method to get the page to run and immediately set the

image to recyclerView?

Comment: Can you post what have you tried i.e the piece of code and the error log ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without any code from your end, what I can suggest is to do something like :

```
recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                     // Execute your AsyncTask here by providing Width
                }
            });
```

Because the problem I can guess is your `RecyclerView` is not properly inflated when you call the AsyncTask with width

Also I would suggest you to put the method after you call `setAdapter`

Comment: I will have to enter code and error next time. Thank you for your advice. Have a nice day!